# My listview stays the same after I enter a different search

Tags: android, android-listview

I have been fixing an app that allows users to search for contacts. I am having a problem with the listview that lists different contacts or locations. If you first search by name and then after you complete that search you turn around and search by location the listview has the previous results in it. I am new to Android and would appreciate any help. Thanks

my code is here

http://sdrv.ms/RY068w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you populate with contacts. When you search again you have to notify the listview that it's content need to update. So you do exactly as you did with contacts but with locations and then call

```
listadapter.notifySetDataChanged()
```

Which tells it to redraw